# What should the home page on a personal site be?

Tags: personal-website

I just finished school for web development and now I'm looking for a programming job. I've built a personal website to show off my work. I've got my resume on there, with a link to my portfolio and a few other things. But one thing I'm struggling with is the home page. Everything I think of either could go on a page I already have or just seems weird and out of place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need much to showcase your work. Keep it simple, create a website that is very minimal. This page shows 5 nice CV / Resume style website templates giving you an idea of how to layout your site to send potential employers to.

http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/web-roundups/5-examples-of-beautiful-resumecv-templates/